# KnockoutJS and c# view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, knockout.js

Maybe is a trivial question, but I need assistance on this. In short, this is a portion of my view-model file, and it works fine when the project is compiled in debug mode:

```
var getValidDocs = function () {
        if (exports.data.Language() == 'it-IT' && exports.data.TaxCode() != null) {

            exports.validRegistrationFiles.removeAll();

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(exports.allValidRegistrationFiles(), function (myRegistrationFile) {

                var titolo = myRegistrationFile.Title._latestValue;
                //Here the browser gives me an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"
                if (isIva.test(exports.data.TaxCode()) && titolo.includes('si_partita_iva')) {
                    exports.validRegistrationFiles.push(myRegistrationFile);
                }
                if (!isIva.test(exports.data.TaxCode()) && titolo.includes('no_partita_iva')) {
                    exports.validRegistrationFiles.push(myRegistrationFile);
                }

            })
            console.log(exports.validRegistrationFiles());
        }
    };
```

but when I compile in release mode, I can't access

`myRegistrationFile.Title._latestValue` property.

Consequently, I can't do

`titolo.includes('si_partita_iva')`

because is undefined. Well, is there a property, equivalent to _latestValue, that I can use in this case?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Avoid using `_latestValue` property as its only on knockout.debug.js iirc.  you should just need `var titolo = myRegistrationFile.Title()`. to get the current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end this is what I did

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root.validRegistrationFiles -->
<div class="row">

    <!-- ko if: $root.checkIVA -->
    <!-- ko if: Title().includes('si_partita_iva') -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 icon">blah blah blah</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: $root.checkCodFiscale -->
    <!-- ko if: Title().includes('no_partita_iva') -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 icon">blah blah blah</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

because everything else has failed miserably